# C++ Functions in loop/struct

Tags: c++, function, loops, struct

Here is my unaltered working code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
const int MAXACCOUNTS = 8;
int interest(int Balance, int MAXACCOUNTS);
struct Account
{
int Number;
double Balance;
int DaysSinceDebited;
};

int main()

{
int Accountnumber;
double Balance;
int DaysSinceDebited;
double Total[MAXACCOUNTS] = {};


Account accounts[MAXACCOUNTS];

accounts[0].Number = 1001;
accounts[0].Balance = 4254.40;
accounts[0].DaysSinceDebited = 20;

accounts[1].Number = 7940;
accounts[1].Balance = 270006.25;
accounts[1].DaysSinceDebited = 35;

accounts[2].Number = 4382;
accounts[2].Balance = 123.50;
accounts[2].DaysSinceDebited = 2;

accounts[3].Number = 2651;
accounts[3].Balance = 85326.92;
accounts[3].DaysSinceDebited = 14;

accounts[4].Number = 3020;
accounts[4].Balance = 657.0;
accounts[4].DaysSinceDebited = 5;

accounts[5].Number = 7168;
accounts[5].Balance = 7423.34;
accounts[5].DaysSinceDebited = 360;

accounts[6].Number = 6285;
accounts[6].Balance = 4.99;
accounts[6].DaysSinceDebited = 1;

accounts[7].Number = 9342;
accounts[7].Balance = 107964.44;
accounts[7].DaysSinceDebited = 45;





for (int i = 0; i < MAXACCOUNTS; i++)
{

if ((accounts[i].Balance > 10000) || (accounts[i].DaysSinceDebited>30))
    Total[i] = accounts[i].Balance * 1.06; //6% interest added
else Total[i] = accounts[i].Balance * 1.03; //3% interest added
cout << accounts[i].Number << " has a balance of " << accounts[i].Balance <<  ". The amount with interest is: " << Total[i] << endl;

system("pause");
}
}
```

Here is what i need to do: You must add a function to your program called CalcInterest. This function will take as its ONLY parameter an Account, and return the Interest calculated as shown in Part 1. Your main program should now use this function instead, to generate the display as in Part 1.

This is what i tried:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

 const int MAXACCOUNTS = 8;
 int CalcInterest(Account);
 struct Account { //declare struct outside of main

int Number;
double Balance;
int DaysSinceDebited;

};



int main()

{

int AccountNumber[MAXACCOUNTS] = { 1001, 7940, 4382, 2651, 3020, 7168, 6245, 9342 };

double Balance[MAXACCOUNTS] = { 4254.40, 27006.25, 123.50, 85326.92, 657.0, 7423.34, 4.99, 107864.44 };

int DaysSinceDebited[MAXACCOUNTS] = { 20, 35, 2, 14, 5, 360, 1, 45 };
double Total[MAXACCOUNTS] = {};
//add your code here



Account accounts[MAXACCOUNTS];

accounts[0].Number = 1001;
accounts[0].Balance = 4254.40;
accounts[0].DaysSinceDebited = 20;

accounts[1].Number = 7940;
accounts[1].Balance = 270006.25;
accounts[1].DaysSinceDebited = 35;

accounts[2].Number = 4382;
accounts[2].Balance = 123.50;
accounts[2].DaysSinceDebited = 2;

accounts[3].Number = 2651;
accounts[3].Balance = 85326.92;
accounts[3].DaysSinceDebited = 14;

accounts[4].Number = 3020;
accounts[4].Balance = 657.0;
accounts[4].DaysSinceDebited = 5;

accounts[5].Number = 7168;
accounts[5].Balance = 7423.34;
accounts[5].DaysSinceDebited = 360;

accounts[6].Number = 6285;
accounts[6].Balance = 4.99;
accounts[6].DaysSinceDebited = 1;

accounts[7].Number = 9342;
accounts[7].Balance = 107964.44;
accounts[7].DaysSinceDebited = 45;



CalcInterest(Account);

}


int CalcInterest(Account) {

for (int i = 0; i < MAXACCOUNTS; i++)
{

    if ((accounts[i].Balance > 10000) || (accounts[i].DaysSinceDebited > 30))

        Total[i] = accounts[i].Balance * 1.06;
    else Total[i] = accounts[i].Balance * 1.03;
    cout << accounts[i].Number << "has a balance of " << accounts[i].Balance  << ". The amount with interest is : " << Total[i] << endl;
}
system("pause");
return 0;

}
```

There were many errors with this, mostly of things becoming undefined, such as .DaysSinceDebited etc PLEASE HELP!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it asks to program for OP

Comment: No, they just don't understand the compilation errors they are getting..  It would have been helpful to show those errors, but all they are really asking for help with is some misunderstandings they have with refactoring.

Comment: 'accounts' is undefined, 'total' is undefined, main local functions are illegal, there are a good few more of these, im looking for the correct way to refactor this

Comment: For future reference, if you are getting compilation errors that you don't understand, it's *crucial* that you put those in your question.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that by "there are many errors", you are talking about compilation errors.  A quick look at your code confirms this.

The first mistake you made is that this function only works on a single account.  You therefore cannot loop over your accounts array inside that function, neither can you access `Total`.  You are also a little confused about the syntax of passing arguments, as well as the datatype that should be returned.  I can help you with that.

Change your function definition to:

```
double CalcInterest( const Account & account )
{
    // Do your interest calculation on 'account' here, then return it from the function.
    double interest = 0.0;  //<-- For you to do.
    return interest;
}
```

Then you can simplify your loop in `main`...

```
for (int i = 0; i < MAXACCOUNTS; i++)
{
    // Calculate the interest on the account, then do something with it.
    double interest = CalcInterest( accounts[i] );
    Total[i] = 0.0;  //<-- For you to do.
}
```

Note that I've only provided the language structure here, since this is obviously an assignment of some sort.  I have indicated the parts where you need to do some work.

Comment: Thankyou will have a go at it now!

Comment: double CalcInterest( const Account & accounts) {

 for (int i = 0; i < MAXACCOUNTS; i++)
 {

  if ((accounts[i].Balance > 10000) || (accounts[i].DaysSinceDebited>30))
   double Total[i] = CalcInterest(accounts[i].Balance * 1.06); //6% interest added
  else double Total[i] = CalcInterest(accounts[i].Balance * 1.03); //3% interest added

  cout << accounts[i].Number << " has a balance of " << accounts[i].Balance << ". The amount with interest is: " << Total[i] << endl;

  system("pause");
  return Total;
 }



} That is what i tried and still have a ton of errors which i will also post

Comment: I think you need to read my answer again.  Then read it three more times.

Comment: the task says "  This function will take as its ONLY parameter an Account, and return the Interest calculated " so is double CalcInterest( const Account & account ) okay to use?

Comment: Yes, that takes ONLY an account.  You can pass by value (`Account account`) if you want, but I am passing a const reference which is how you normally do it in C++.  The return type of `double` is correct.

Comment: okay thanks, just need some clarification on what im supposed to be doing here: double interest = 0.0;  //<-- For you to do.

Comment: Well, that's of course the part where you calculate the interest on the account, as I pointed out in the comment just above that line.  I'm not going to do your homework for you, sorry!  It appears from your working code that you already know what to do in order to calculate the interest on a single account.

Comment: I think im getting through it down to 3 errors now.                                                 double CalcInterest(Account & account);
 {

  for (int i = 0; i < MAXACCOUNTS; i++)
  {

   if ((accounts[i].Balance > 10000) || (accounts[i].DaysSinceDebited > 30))
    Total[i] = accounts[i].Balance * 1.06;  
   else Total[i] = accounts[i].Balance * 1.03;  
   double interest = CalcInterest(accounts[i]);
   Total[i] = 0.0; 
   cout << accounts[i].Number << " has a balance of " << accounts[i].Balance << ". The amount with interest is: " << Total[i] << endl;

   system("pause");

  }


 }

Comment: would you be kind enough to tell me if that looks better?

Comment: No, it sort of looks like you need to read my answer (specifically the second paragraph) three more times.

Comment: Really sorry if im annoying you, just this is the last part of a sample test of one i have in a few hours! I am struggling with this, i have come up with this after reading over the second paragraph, trying to not loop over accounts, any improvement? double CalcInterest(const Account & accounts);
 {

  if ((accounts.Balance > 10000) || (accounts.DaysSinceDebited > 30))
   double interest = account.Balance * 1.06;
  else double interest = accounts.Balance * 1.03;
  return interest;
 }

Comment: Im still having so much trouble, if you could provide the solution i would be very greatful, i will study it and learn it!

Comment: You are close.  The only problem is you are declaring the variable `interest` inside the `if` and `else` blocks.  That means when you go to return `interest` at the end of the function, it's no longer in scope.  Declare the variable at the top of the function, then change its value in the `if` section.  Also, multiplying by `1.xx` is computing the combined interest (balance plus interest).  I thought the function is supposed to compute the interest only.